# Is there a mean to handle cancel request in .net core webapi middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a middleware in my API that handle request but not cancel request send by browsers.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {    
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        var test = "";
    }
}
```

In business or repo layer, I have the variable

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested
```

set to true and have the possibilities to cancel execution of my code but I have to add this piece of code in several places so I would like to handle cancel request in order to kill the associated task directly in the middleware if there is possible but I don't find any examples to do that.

I also try to add this in business and repo function but without any effect :

```
HttpContext.RequestAborted.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to handle cancel request in order to kill the associated task directly in the middleware

This is not possible. Cancellation in .NET is cooperative, so any code you want to cancel must observe the token for cancellation. `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is one way to do this, but it's more common to just pass the `CancellationToken` down to the other methods called by your code.